# Implementing Task Runner for store output in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5, sencha-architect

I'm fairly new to ExtJS and I'm kinda stuck in one of the problems so I need your help.

Basically I access my application by using following URL:

```
servername:port/XMII/CM/XYZ/index.html?machine=1&typeofpage=dashboard
```

I get these URL params machine and typeofpage via following code used in global controller getMode():

```
//get the url parameters
var url = window.location.search,
urlParams = Ext.Object.fromQueryString(url);

return {

    machineID: urlParams.machine,
    typeofPage: urlParams.typeofpage
};
```

Now depending upon the typeofpage, I decide which page to open via following code in the afterrender method of initial viewport:

var mode = this.getMode();

```
if(mode.typeofpage=== 'dashboard') {

      panel = Ext.create('XYZ.view.Dashboard',{
        ID_MACHINE: mode.machineID
    });

          component.add(panel);

}
```

So above code calls my dashboard page correctly passing machineID as 1 properly.

With this machineID property, I pass that to store MachineParts and this store gives me all of hte machine parts for machine ID 1. Following is the code in aferrender of XYZ.view.Dashboard:

```
var me = this,
    machinepartIds= [];

Ext.defer(function(){

    component.mask('Loading...');

    me.getStore('MachinePart').load({
            params:{
                'Param.1': component.ID_MACHINE
            },
            callback: function(response) {
                component.unmask();
                Ext.each(response, function(panel) {
                    machinepartIds.push(panel.get('MachinePartID'));

                });
   alert('Machine IDs: ' + machinepartIds.toString();
        }
    });
},10);
```

So lets say it gives me back following data:

```
MachineID    MachinePartID
   1               20
   1               21
   1               22
```

Now I have a function called loadKPIs which takes parameter as ID - that is machinepartID. I use this loadKPIs function to populate all of the KPIs on the page and display them for a particular machinepart ID as a dashboard.

I want to pass machinepartIDs 20,21,22 to the loadKPIs function every 10 min so that I can show the dashboard for each machinepart for 10 min.

For example, I will start with machinepart ID 20. after 10 min, I would like to pass achinepart ID as 21. After 10 min I would like to pass machinepart ID as 22. Then again back to 20 after 10 min. I'm sure I need to use TaskRunner but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as the answer using the checkbox in that answer. Up voting isn't enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `Ext.util.TaskManager` to call a function at an interval and have a friendly API and control to start/stop whenever you want, here's a simple code snippet:

```
var task = Ext.util.TaskManager.newTask({
    interval : 600000,
    scope    : this,
    run      : function() {}
});

Ext.util.TaskManager.start(task);
```

or of course you can use `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function() {
    doSomething();
}, 6000000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to setup a timer either in the app or inside the dashboard. E.g.

```
var machineParts = [20, 21, 22];
setTimeout(function() {
    YourApp.app.redirectTo('servername:port/XMII/CM/XYZ/index.html?machine=' + machinParts.shift() + '&typeofpage=dashboard');
}, 10 * 60 * 1000);
```

However this will result reload of that page so probably it is better to implement something similar in you dashboard what would change only the panel where you display the machine part related content.

Comment: machine will always stay as 1 or 2 in the URL. Depending upon the machine ID (1 or 2), I will get machine parts (20,21,22). I need to call loadKPI function for machine parts 20,21,22 at every 10 minutes.

Comment: Add a similar timer to your dashboard code then which calls you loadKPI function.